# focusin and focusout is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

jQuery Version: 1.10.1

I am attempting to write a tooltip what will be shown when clicking on each image items of list. However before clicking on item, the tooltip is showing the html content like [image] when hovering mouse. Please see my attempt below:

```js
$('#main_8').attr('title', function () {
                            //$('#test').attr('title', function () {
                            //return "<div> hello </div>";
                            return $("#cat_8").remove().html();
                        });
                        $(document).ready(function (e) {
                            $('#main_8').tooltip({
                                //$('#test').tooltip({
                                content: function () {
                                    return $(this).prop('title');
                                },
                                position: {
                                    my: 'center bottom',
                                    at: 'center top-10',
                                    using: function (position, feedback) {
                                        $(this).css(position);
                                        $("<div>")
                                          .addClass("arrow")
                                          .addClass(feedback.vertical)
                                          .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
                                          .appendTo(this);
                                    }

                                },

                                disabled: true
                            }).on("focusin", function () {
                                $(this)
                                    .tooltip("enable")
                                    .tooltip("open");
                            }).on("focusout", function () {
                                $(this)
                                    .tooltip("close")
                                    .tooltip("disable");
                            });

                        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
                        <div id="main_8" class="tile-video category-item" tabindex="99" title="Hello">
                            <a class="thumb" data-method="cat_8">
                                <img src="/Content/CmsContent/VideoIcons/no-image-small.jpg">
                            </a>
                            <h3>
                                <a data-method="cat_8"> Innovation &amp; Succession Planning Series </a>
                            </h3>
                        </div>

                    </div>
<div id="cat_8">
 <b>This is cat 8</b>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try to disable tooltip of **main** `div` before calling `focusin` and `focusout`. See my example code below:

```
$('#main_8').attr('title', function () {
  $(this).tooltip({disabled:true});
  return $("#cat_8").remove().html();
});
```

Hopefully, it's helpful for you.

Comment: I attempted but it's still error..ok let me try from my asp.net MVC where I faced this problem.

Comment: yeah, it works with me. I understood now. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with your Javascript code. The problem is with your HTML. You have:

```
<div id="main_8" class="tile-video category-item" tabindex="99" title="
```

The quote at the end starts the title string, and everything up to this line

```
</div><!-- div.list-sub-category -->
">
```

is being taken as the title of the DIV. So when you hover over the DIV, it displays all that HTML text.

You need to put a normal title there, and fix up all the HTML in the middle so it doesn't use HTML entities in place of all the quotes around attributes.

Comment: I don't see the problem any more when I run your snippet.